# Why is a current carrying coil most unstable at 180 degree in uniform magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

When the coil is at 180 degree, it experiences 0 torque, and when it is at 90 degree, it experiences torque = mB
So, comparing, the coil should be more stable at 180 degree. But there is a gain in potential energy by bringing the coil from 90 to 180 degree. 
I know the integration, the right hand thumb rule for rotation and the formula. I also know that even at 135 degree the torque will rotate it to 0 degree but it doesn't make sense. What's wrong at 180?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Stability" is not defined by where an object is not moving.

Consider balancing a pencil. In an ideal world, if you try hard enough, you can *just* balance the pencil on its tip. But being even slightly off, or perturbing it ever so slightly, will cause the pencil to fall. That's because, even though the pencil isn't moving, it is in an unstable equilibrium, at the top of a maximum of gravitational potential.

The coil is similar. At 180°, the potential energy is maximized, so the coil is at the very top of a potential energy maximum. It will rest there with no torque ideally, but even the slightest push will cause it to experience torque and eventually reach 0° due to that torque. For that reason, the 180° configuration is called "unstable."